# Behaviour of div properties

Tags: html, css

I've noticed a strange behaviour of the div tag (in my opinion and with my knowledge of HTML & CSS).
I'm building a site with a custom grid system, and if I don't apply the floating attribute (left or right) the div in which I apply the grid class won't notice the margin properties.

The code:

```
.grid-100 {width: 100%;}
.grid-60 { width: 65%;  float: left;}
.grid-30 { width: 33%;  float: left;}
.grid-100, .grid-60, .grid-30 { margin-top: 30px;}
```

If I don't set `float:left;` to .grid-100 the div with this class won't apply the margin-top to 30px.

Can anybody give me an explanation?

Comment: There must be something else to your problem http://jsfiddle.net/esvLa/ do you not see the margin top?

Comment: Can you provide a complete code example that illustrates the issue? I'm guessing collapsing margins, but without a complete picture it's only a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

The normal behavior is:

> **Parent and first/last child**
>       If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first
>   child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height,
>   min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block
>   with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse.
>   The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

When you float them:

> Margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.